# Unpacking slice of slices

Tags: go, slice, variadic-functions

I am curious about unpacking a slice of slices and sending them as arguments to a variadic function.

Let's say we have a function with variadic parameters:

```
func unpack(args ...interface{})
```

If we wan't to pass in a slice of interfaces it works, it doesn't matter if we unpack it or not:

```
slice := []interface{}{1,2,3}
unpack(slice) // works
unpack(slice...) // works
```

It gets tricky if we have a slice of slices. Here the compiler doesn't let us pass in an unpacked version:

```
sliceOfSlices := [][]interface{}{
    []interface{}{1,2},
    []interface{}{101,102},
}
unpack(sliceOfSlices) // works
unpack(sliceOfSlices...) // compiler error
```

The error says:

> cannot use sliceOfSlices (type [][]interface {}) as type []interface {} in argument to unpack

I don't know why this happens, as we can clearly pass an `[]interface{}` type into the function. How can I call the method unpack with the unpacked content of `sliceOfSlices` as arguments?

Playground example: https://play.golang.org/p/O3AYba8h4i

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is covered in [Spec: Passing arguments to ... parameters](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters):

> If `f` is variadic with a final parameter `p` of type `...T`, then within `f` the type of `p` is equivalent to type `[]T`.
>
> ...
>
> **If the final argument is assignable to a slice type `[]T`, it may be passed unchanged as the value for a `...T` parameter if the argument is followed by `...`.** In this case no new slice is created.

**So in short:** it is a compile-time error because `sliceOfSlices` (which is of type `[][]interface{}`) cannot be assigned to `args` (which is of type `[]interface{}`) ([proof on Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Pu2Zo9_kIl)).

**In long:**

In your first example when you do `unpack(slice)`, since `unpack()` expects values of `interface{}`, therefore `slice` (which is of type `[]interface{}`) will be wrapped in a *new* `interface{}` value, and it will be passed as a *single* argument.

When you do `unpack(slice...)`, this will pass all the values of `slice` as separate values to `unpack()`; this is possible because type of `slice` is `[]interface{}`, it matches the type of the variadic parameter (`args ...interface{}`).

In your second example when you do `unpack(sliceOfSlices)`, again, `sliceOfSlices` will be wrapped in a *new* `interface{}` value and passed as a *single* argument.

But when you try `unpack(sliceOfSlices...)`, that would want to pass each element of `sliceOfSlices` to `unpack()`, but type of `sliceOfSlices` (which is `[][]interface{}`) does not match the type of the variadic parameter, hence the compile-time error.

The only way to pass `sliceOfSlices` to `unpack()` "exploded" is to create a new slice whose type must be `[]interface{}`, copy the elements, then you can pass it using `...`.

Example:

```
var sliceOfSlices2 []interface{}
for _, v := range sliceOfSlices {
    sliceOfSlices2 = append(sliceOfSlices2, v)
}

unpack(sliceOfSlices2...)
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/0mc2V5PSoD).

Let's use the following `unpack()` function to verify the number of arguments:

```
func unpack(args ...interface{}) {
    fmt.Println(len(args))
}
```

Running your example (and with my new slice creation), output is:

```
1
3
1
2
```

Which proves without `...` only a single argument is passed (wrapped in `interface{}`), and using `...` all elements will be passed separately.

Try this test on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/s95l3ERKpB).