# Variadic Variable Expansion in fmt.Println

Tags: go, variadic-functions, variadic

```
package main
import "fmt"
func main(){
        a := []int{1,2,3}
        fmt.Println(a...)
}
```

Running this gives the following error

`./program.go:5: cannot use a (type []int) as type []interface {} in argument to fmt.Println`

From `godoc fmt Println`

```
func Println(a ...interface{}) (n int, err error)
```

`Println` accepts any value because it is an empty interface.

What's confusing to me is that

`fmt.Println(a...)` is same as `fmt.Println(a[0],a[1],a[2])`

and yet one works but the other doesn't.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[]int` is not the same as `[]interface{}`, so if you have an `[]int`, you can't pass that to `fmt.Println()` as the value for the variadic slice. You may pass it as-is, but that's gonna be an `[]interface{}` slice with a single value being the `[]int` slice.

`fmt.Println(a...)` is **not** the same as `fmt.Println(a[0],a[1],a[2])`.

`fmt.Println(a[0], a[1], a[2])` is equivalent to

```
fmt.Println([]interface{}{a[0], a[1], a[2]}...)
```

which is equivalent to

```
fmt.Println([]interface{}{
    interface{}(a[0]),
    interface{}(a[1]),
    interface{}(a[2]),
}...)
```

So when you pass `a[0]`, `a[1]` and `a[2]`, implicit `interface{}` values will be created, which will be implicitly wrapped in a slice.

If you would want to pass elements of `a` to a function that expects a variadic parameter of `[]interface{}`, you have to "manually" create that slice beforehand, e.g.:

```
b := make([]interface{}, len(a))
for i, v := range a {
    b[i] = v
}
fmt.Println(b...)
```

Try these examples on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/JgjKHOUSKT8).

Also see related question: [Unpacking slice of slices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39914447/unpacking-slice-of-slices/39915311#39915311)